# HybridAuth (Anvard) - How to log out & log in as different user?

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-4, hybridauth

I'm using [Anvard](https://bitbucket.org/atticmedia/anvard), a Laravel package which implements Hybridauth. All the questions I've been reading are asking about logging *in* automatically, and I need the opposite!

Scenario:

- UserA is logged in using LinkedIn
- click logout to hit the `/anvard/logout` route
- user is redirected to `/login` with a 'logged out' flash message
- click the 'login with LinkedIn' button
- UserA is automatically authenticated without requiring reauthorisation

**How can UserB log in (using the same browser) using LinkedIn?**

UserA could go to their linked in settings and un-authorise the app, but that's obviously impractical :)

I've tried using the 'anvard/logout' route and have also tried adding the following to my /logout route:

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {

    // this is drawn from anvard's logout function
    $hybridAuth = App::make('hybridauth');
    $hybridAuth->logoutAllProviders();

    // this not working either :(
    // if(Auth::check()) {
    //     Auth::user()->remember_token = NULL;
    // }

    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return Redirect::route('login')->with('success', 'You\'ve been Logged Out');
});
```

As you can see.. I'm just trying it all :)

Here's an issue I found at hybridauth: [Logout doesn't really logout #220](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/220)

---

Update:

*Am I just missing a basic principle? Is it simply that only one user may be auth'd with any given provider in a given browser at a time, and to allow another user to sign in, UserA must visit his provider (LinkedIn) and log out?*

There is a helpful answer and a useful comment over at [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2791/invalidating-access-token-vs-de-auth-app):

> Ok so if an invalid Access Token is used, the API will return an
>   error, it is then up to the app to run the user through the auth
>   process again. The app does so, if the user is logged in already and
>   the app is still authorised, the auth flow will invisibly use the
>   cookies/local storage/etc, or otherwise present the OAuth dialog,
>   right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works like the Facebook Login. If I am currently on my computer logged in via facebook and then login via your application, your app makes the connection between my facebook account and the account of your website.

If I logout, only my session on your website is destroyed and I am logged out from your website. This has no impact on my logged in status on facebook. If I visit the facebook website now, I will still be logged in via my facebook account. Therefore, if I again visit your website and login via facebook, I will be logged in with my associated account.

So if another person wants to login, I first have to go to facebook and logout. The other person has to login on FB and can then login on your website with his facebook credentials.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: yup, i couldn't see the forest for the trees, thanks!